# How to check if a date is not present in multiple ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table called 'Buildings'. The table lists date ranges when the buildings were active. The IDs for the buildings are sometimes duplicated. Using TSQL I want to get all the distinct buildings that were not active on this day (20181013), but I have no idea how. Could you please help me?
Ideally, what I should get would be buildings no. 2 and 3.

Buildings:

```
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| Building_ID | LineID | Active_from | Active_to |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |      1 |    20170101 |  20190101 |
|           2 |      1 |    20170203 |  20170903 |
|           2 |      2 |    20170904 |  20171231 |
|           2 |      3 |    20180101 |  20180910 |
|           2 |      4 |    20181101 |  20181231 |
|           3 |      1 |    20170101 |  20180631 |
|           3 |      2 |    20190101 |  20200101 |
|           4 |      1 |    20180101 |  20180631 |
|           4 |      2 |    20180701 |  20190101 |
+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
    cte
as
(
    select
        Building_ID
    from
        [Your_Table]
    where
        '20181013' between Active_from and Active_to
)
select
distinct
    Building_ID
from
    [Your_Table] yt
where
    Building_ID not in
    (
        select
            Building_ID
        from
            cte
    )
```

Comment: An explanation of your code *always* makes your answer better

Comment: For Pete's sake, that was so easy, and yet so brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be written straight forward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Building_ID
FROM Buildings b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM Buildings
  WHERE '20181013' BETWEEN Active_from AND Active_to
    AND Building_ID = b.Building_ID)
```